# Python - Checking how many instances of strings are embedded within strings

Tags: python, python-3.x

Given the following Python script:

```
types_of_people = 10
x = f"There are {types_of_people} types of people."

binary = "binary"
do_not = "don't"
y = f"Those who know {binary} and those who {do_not}." # 2 instances

print(x)
print(y)

print(f"I said: {x}") # 1 instance
print(f"I also said: '{y}'") # 1 instance

hilarious = False
joke_evaluation = "Isn't that joke so funny?! {}"

print(joke_evaluation.format(hilarious))

w = "This is the left side of..."
e = "a string with a right side."

print(w + e)
```

How many instances of strings embedded within strings occur?

The reason I am asking because I'm learning and was told to perform a count of these instances, which I think there are 4 of. However the teaching resource has gone on to say there could be more than 4 instances.

Apologies if the phrasing seems ambiguous, or terminology seems off. I'm trying to keep things simple while I learn the language.

My understanding is that there are 4, which I have commented in the script. However I believe there could be more, please advise if possible, help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I get;

```
types_of_people = 10
x = f"There are {types_of_people} types of people." #First instance

binary = "binary"
do_not = "don't"
y = f"Those who know {binary} and those who {do_not}." #Second and third instances

print(x)
print(y)

print(f"I said: {x}") # #Fourth instance
print(f"I also said: '{y}'") #Fifth instance

hilarious = False
joke_evaluation = "Isn't that joke so funny?! {}" #Sixth instance (shared with below line)

print(joke_evaluation.format(hilarious)) #Shared sixth instance

w = "This is the left side of..."
e = "a string with a right side."

print(w + e)
```

Any instances of an f string (`f'foobar {variable}'`) or a string succeded with the `.format()` function (`'foobar {0}'.format(variable)`) are embedding strings within string.

Comment: Hang on a second - types_of_people is an integer data type, so therefore your first instance is incorrect - this is an int within a string surely? Or is the case that I'm mistaken and the int is converted to a string when it is output?

Comment: You are right that it's an integer, but what `f` strings do is evaulate any calculations within the `{}` brackets and then automatically converts the result to string.

Comment: Ah alright thank you, and finally in your sixth instance the hilarious variable that is a boolean is also converted to a string when formatted?

Comment: consider the following f string: `f'Five plus five is: {5 + 5}'`, python evaluates the calculation `5+5`, and returns the result as a string `'10'`

Comment: Exactly correct! Also a side note, you need 3.6+ in order to use f strings as they were not introduced in earlier versions